# Electromagnet Wire/Voltage/Magnets?

Tags: voltage, wire, electromagnetic, magnet

I have some questions about my project. I want to make a big electromagnet, the size is about:

Outer Ring:

- 50-70cm Height
- 35cm Diameter

Inner Ring (The Movement):

- 32cm Diameter

Now:

1. is it OK to use 1mm copper wire?
2. How much voltage do I need for a nice movement?
3. Must the inner ring be a whole magnet, or is it OK to make many small magnets on the inner ring?

[image]

Comment: what does this mean? `for a nice movement`

Comment: you need an iron core for the electromagnet

Comment: So for the inner ring , no magnets just an iron core ?

Comment: A silicon steel core, or ferrite if the OP is rich enough...

Comment: There is no budget given so no worries there!!

Comment: why do you need an inner ring? ... is what you said that you are making different from what you are actually making?

Comment: let's have a better, labelled, picture of what you intend to make. You may be trying to make something more complicated than what you need.

Comment: I need something to move the inner ring linear without touching the walls or touching the inner walls of the inner ring. So a linear movement of the "inner Ring". Like a solenoid i think.

Comment: On the Top and the Bottom it will be touch/stop but by the movement it must be completely free of the outer ring.

Comment: It's Ok to use a 1mm if you don't use high current. Check this link https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibre_de_alambre_estadounidense

Comment: @Dimitri I don't understand _anything_ in that link.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It's similar to Bruces link. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge

Comment: The inner metal core will try to find the position of lowest reluctance (I think it was).  It will levitate to the middle of the solenoid (with some gravity droop) but will very likely be touching one side.

Comment: Seems similar to a speaker voice coil, or a solenoid. Other than that we are guessing and OP offers little help. VTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it okey to take a 1mm Copperwire?

Yes. A single layer 60cm long will have 545 turns and need 600m of wire.

> How much Voltage do i need , for a nice movement?

13 Volts. The coil will draw ~1 Amp. The movement will be very nice (synonyms: enjoyable, pleasant, delightful, entertaining, amusing). You could use up to 65V (which should draw 5A) but the coil will get hotter and the movement could get quite ugly.

> Must be the inner Ring be a whole magnet or is it ok , to make many small magnets on the inner ring?

It's OK to put many small magnets on the inner ring - if you can get them to stay there. The magnets should all be oriented in the same direction, eg. north pole up, south pole down.

Resources used for calculations:-

[Solenoid calculator](http://electronbunker.ca/eb/InductanceCalc.html)

[AWG gauges and their current ratings](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/wire-gauges-d_419.html)

Comment: Thank you for the very good answer ! -That is huge length of wire, is it possible to use a 2-5mm Copperwire with 12v and i will still get the nice(smooth) movement or how is it with the movement?  Do i need for a bigger wire more voltage or less? I think the current is the point for the movement right?

Comment: Magnetic field strength is proportional to both current and number of turns. Stronger magnetic field creates more force and faster movement. Current is determined by Ohm's Law (I=V/R) and so can be increased by raising voltage and/or using thicker wire. However increasing current and/or voltage also increases power and heating (P=IV). If the coil gets too hot it will melt or burn.